# Lightweight software to post-record video

Tags: screen-recording

I'm looking for a software that would allow me to post-record videos of gameplay. For example, I'm playing Battlefield 4, I just did some very nice tow, or came across a glitch, I'd like to be able to record it after, so to save to disk the last minute of gameplay. I'm on a budget laptop with i5 6300HQ GTX 950M where performance is an issue, particulary with heavy games such as BF4.

I already tried Nvidia share. The performance impact is quite low, but I recently I have been unable to use it and it requires connecting to their servers for no reasons. It also has a performance impact on startup, I sometimes get desktop not responding because of Nvidia. I also tried Microsoft tool, DVR. The impact on startup seems good, but this severely impact performance while gaming, making the game completely unplayable.

So I'd like to be able to record the last minute with little impact before and after recoring, and also no boot slowdown.

Comment: What OS are you running on? If you are on Windows 10, take a look at [This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/a4cced71-b833-4e48-8523-8be8b7d29448/keyboard-shortcuts-for-game-bar)

Comment: Thanks, but it severly impacts performance

Comment: Speaking from experience, Shadowplay is probably the lowest impact on performance program that you can find that can actively record and save past events in games. Since Shadowplay is directly connected to the NVidia GPU you have, it is the closest to no performance impact you can get. A possible solution to the heavy performance impacts you are seeing on startup is checking to make sure your drivers are up to date, as well as disabling some other programs from startup that you do not use or need.

Comment: Unfortunalety, shadowplay now requires  sign up and send telemetry data to nvidia ...

Comment: An alternative to shadowplay which I use on Linux is ffmpeg. It's available for Windows too. When compiled with NVENC support it uses the hardware the same way shadowplay does. Being just a tool for recording, you'd have to implement the constant recording yourself, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: I suck at C++ unfortunately. Maybe with C# it's easier :)